# Adding prefix in an update statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, concatenation

I have the following MySQL code:

```
UPDATE opened_pw SET opened_date_week = CONCAT('WK', WEEK(opened_date))
```

What I intend to do here is change the `opened_date_week` columns with a prefix of 'WK' followed by the week conversion of the `opened_date` column.

**EDIT:**

How do I add a 'WK ' standard prefix to all the conversions so that whatever is stored in opened_date_week will be like this `WK 13 WK 14`?

If I execute: `UPDATE opened_pw SET opened_date_week = WEEK(opened_date)` It makes the changes but that statement doesn't include the prefix of `'WK '`

Comment: Okay. What's then?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I add a 'WK ' standard prefix to all the conversions so that whatever is stored in opened_date_week will be like this

WK 13
WK 14

Comment: You are doing right. Did u run this? Just add a space after 'WK'

Comment: I did and there are no changes made. If I execute: UPDATE opened_pw SET opened_date_week = WEEK(opened_date)

It makes the changes but that statement doesn't include the prefix of 'WK '

Comment: Okay. What's the data type of `opened_date_week`? It should be varchar

Comment: That was the solution, thank you. I had the column set to an integer Please post this so that I can mark your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the datatype of `opened_date_week` column to `VARCHAR`.

```
ALTER TABLE opened_pw MODIFY opened_date_week VARCHAR(10);
```

After altering the datatype you can now execute your update query and check the result.

```
UPDATE opened_pw SET opened_date_week = CONCAT('WK ', WEEK(opened_date));
```